# SQNR and Dynamic Range

Tags: audio, signal-to-noise, digital-audio

An audio tone \$Acos(\omega t + \theta)\$ undergoes uniform quantization by a quantizer that has the average quantization noise power \$q^2/6\$ joules, where \$q\$ is the quantization step size. If the dynamic range of the quantizier is adjusted to 15dB and the signal-to-quantization-noise ratio (SQNR) is targeted to be at least 40dB, how many bits per sample are needed to code each sample?

This is an past-exam exercise from my university. I tried to solve it, but I only got a solution as a function of \$A\$. Anyone can give me a hint? I don't know what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Is this for an over-sampling ADC?

Answer (score 1):

I got to this solution:

Starting from SQNR formula:
\begin{equation}
\text{SQNR} = 10log(\frac{A^2/2}{q^2/6})
\end{equation}
simplified:
\begin{equation}
\text{SQNR} = 4.77 + 20log(\frac{A}{q})
\end{equation}
As,
\begin{equation}
q = \frac{2*V_{max}}{2^N}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{SQNR} = 4.77 + 20log(\frac{2^NA}{2V_{max}})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{SQNR} = -1.25 + 6.02N + 20log(\frac{A}{V_{max}})
\end{equation}
Dynamic range in this case:
\begin{equation}
\text{DR} = 20log(\frac{V_{max}}{A})
\end{equation}
Substitution:
\begin{equation}
40 = -1.25 + 6.02N - 15
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
N = 9 \text{ bits (ceiling function)}
\end{equation}

I would appreciate if someone can give his approval!